# i want to get id from tab-content div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get ID of each `tab-content` inner div `tab-pane`

[JS fiddle link:](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1595/)

codes:

```
    jQuery(function () {
    var tabContent = $('.tab-pane');
    $('#myTab').on('click', function(){
 if(tabContent).hasClass('active'){
     alert(tabContent).attr('id');
 }
    });
})
```

Comment: The jQuery in your fiddle doesn't match your question's code

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

This will loop over each `.tab-pane` and alert the element's id.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg0ur7o4/).

```
$('.tab-pane').each(function(index, element) {
  alert(element.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1601/

```
$('.tab-pane').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```